# The content of an object is changed after executing a function

Tags: php, class, object

There are two objects of the same class:

```
$obj1 = new MyClass();
$obj2 = new MyClass();
```

Then I applied a function `func` to `$obj2`. However, once this function is executed, I noticed that the content of `$obj1` has magically changed as well. I do not use any reference to `$obj1` inside `func`. What might be the possible reasons of this problem? How do I solve it?

```
$obj2 = func($obj2,$vars);
```

I should say that I use other functions before `func`, and they also use `$obj2` as an input. However, after their execution the content of `$obj1` get not changed.

P.S. When I debug this code in Zend Studio and go inside func, Watch list Expressions says that `$obj1 = null`, but I think it's fine, because `func` is saved in a different PHP file.

Comment: Could you add the code for your function?

Comment: It's a long code. But in general all the steps are around $obj2, something like: $obj2->getVar($i)->setVal(5), etc. It does not use $obj1.

Comment: This will be hard to guess a good answer without your code.

Comment: @Ninsuo: Please see the code in my new topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12359554/code-the-content-of-an-object-is-changed-after-executing-a-function

Comment: @andrewsi: Please see the code in my new topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12359554/code-the-content-of-an-object-is-changed-after-executing-a-function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider this:

```
class MyClass
{
  public static $value;

  public function test( $testvalue )
  {
    self::value = $testvalue;
  }
}

$obj1 = new MyClass();
$obj2 = new MyClass();

$obj1->test( 123 );

echo $obj2::value; // this will echo 123!!
```

There are no changes to made to $obj2, only to $obj1. The static causes the var to loose its object contents, and becomes 'global' to all objects.

Comment: Sorry,I did not get the point.Could you please tell me your suggestion to avoid the problem I described? What would be the easiest solution (I don't want to chage the whole logic)?

Comment: I made the code some cleaner. Avoid singletons, statics and globals.

Comment: The point is: check if there are static (shared) attributes in your class.

Comment: I checked. All my variables inside MyClass (equivalent to your $value) are defined as: private $value; Then I use public function __construct() { $this->$value = 0; } Finally I have public function func(..) inside MyClass. Is it correct?

Comment: It is. As long as you do not use statics inside a class, two instances of the same class have only the methods in common, and the 'state' is unique.

Comment: Hmm, then what might be the reason of this magic?:( And what are effective methods to diagnose the moment when $obj1 i changed?

Comment: You have to show some code, perhaps a __clone, or a wrong assignment? Open a new topic with te code.

Comment: I appreciate if you could take a look at my new topic (including the code) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12359554/code-the-content-of-an-object-is-changed-after-executing-a-function