# CODE - The content of an object is changed after executing a function

Tags: php, class, object

The problem is that the content of `$oldpop` get magically changed after executing the function `func`, whereas the input of `func` is `$matepop`. Inside `func`, `$oldpop` is not used (I added the comment line to show the place - see the end of the code snippet of **MAIN.PHP**). Below I provide just some principal parts of the code. Maybe, someone could suggest the reason of the problem?

I should mention I don't use static variables.

**File MAIN.PHP**

```
include_once 'func.php';
include_once 'select.php';

class Individual {
    private $genes;
    private $rank;

    public function __construct() {
          $this->genes = array();
          $this->rank = 0;
    }

    public function setRank($val){
            $this->rank = $val;
    }

    public function setGene($i,$val){
        $this->genes[$i] = $val;
    }
}

class Population {
    private $ind;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->ind = array();
    }

    public function addIndividual(Individual $ind)
    {
        $this->ind[] = $ind;
    }

    public function getIndividual($i){
        return $this->ind[$i];
    }
  }


    $oldpop = new Population();

  for($i=0; $i<$popsize; $i++) {
    $oldpop->addIndividual(new Individual());
  }

    $oldpop = func($oldpop,$popsize); 

    for ($i = 0; $i < $gener; $i++) 
    {        
        $matepop = new Population();
        $matepop = nselect($matepop,$oldpop,$popsize);

        // !!! Here the $oldpop content is correct (original)
        $matepop = func($matepop,$popsize);
        // !!!! Here the original content of $oldpop is magically changed

    }
```

**File SELECT.PHP**

```
function nselect($matepop,$oldpop,$popsize) { 
  $select = array();
  //...
  $select[] = $oldpop->getIndividual($i);
  //...
  for ($i=0; $i < $popsize; $i++) {
       $matepop->addIndividual($select[$i]);
  }
  return $matepop;
}
```

**File  FUNC.PHP**

```
function func($pop,$popsize) { 
  //...
  $pop->getIndividual($i)->setRank($val);
  //...
  return $pop;
}
```

Comment: Any specific reason why `$matepop` get's overwritten by `new Population();` ? I assume `$gener` has a value greater than 1?

Comment: Yes, exactly. $gener has value 10. But this problem occurs already at $i = 0 (I mean $i -> counter for $gener).

Comment: Looking through all of that code, I only saw `setRank` appear once, and that was when you called it. I assume you DO have a `setRank` method somewhere in your `Individual` class?

Comment: @dbf: at each $i I need to create new $matepop. But even if I do $matepop = new Popolation() before the 0-$gener FOR loop, the problem described in thread still exist.

Comment: @Palladium: yes, correctly: Inside Individual class I have - private $rank;   public function setRank($val){
            $this->rank = $val;
     }

Comment: @Palladium: Please see the updated post with setRank.

Comment: So what is getting changed? Could you do a var_dump($oldpop) before and after the change?

Comment: @dbf: $oldpop is a big object. so, i cannot post var_dump result here. but, in particular, $rank of individuals in $oldpop is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PHP object variables don't contain a full copy of the object; rather, they contain a reference to the object.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/oop5.intro.php) This means that when you used

```
$select[] = $oldpop->getIndividual($i);
```

in your code, you didn't make a new copy of the object `$i`; you simply copied the reference to the object `$i` into the array `$select`. This means that both `$oldpop` and `$matepop` contain references to the *same* objects in their `$ind` arrays. Then, when you later used

```
$pop->getIndividual($i)->setRank($val);
```

to set the rank of each `Individual`-class object in `$matepop`, they also changed for `$oldpop`.

Answer (score 1):

In your `nselect()` function, you're getting individuals from `$oldpop` and then adding them to `$matepop`:

```
$select[] = $oldpop->getIndividual($i);
//...
for ($i=0; $i < $popsize; $i++) {
    $matepop->addIndividual($select[$i]);
}
```

When you do this, this does not "create a copy" of the `individual` and add the copy - it adds a [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php) to the original. So, whatever you do to *any* of the `individuals` added to `$matepop` through this method will consequently be updated in `$oldpop` as well because, well, they're the exact same object.

So, in your `func()` method, when you set the rank on the `individuals` in `$matepop` (and I'm assuming that's the only `individual`-modification you perform in that function) you're modifying the one and only instance of each `individual`, which happens to be referenced in `$matepop` *and* `$oldpop`. This is why you see `$oldpop` modified.

To resolve an issue like this, you'll need to implement some type of [cloning/copying](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) instead of a direct reference.